# How to fill a struct that has lots of nested structs in Go

Tags: go, struct

What is the best way to fill a struct that has lots of nested structs inside it?
I made a struct to generate a json schema file from it that looks like this:

```
type Schema struct {
  Schema               string `default:"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"`
  Title                string `default:"Test Schema"`
  Type                 string `default:"object"`
  AdditionalProperties bool   `default:false`
  Properties           struct {
    Core struct {
      Type                 string
      AdditionalProperties bool
      Properties           struct{}
    }
    Work struct {
      Type                 string
      AdditionalProperties bool
      Properties           struct{}
    }
  }
}
```

At first, I wanted to put the default data in tags and fill the struct from that, but `reflect` package doesn't look inside the nested structs.

Here is what I did using `reflect`:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(Schema{})
for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
    field := t.Field(i)
    tag := field.Tag.Get("default")
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "reflect package doesn't look inside the nested structs"? You can get the type of a field and reflect on it exactly like you did with the outer struct.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is with a constructor method.  This will be more readable, and much faster, than using tags plus reflection. Something like:

```
func NewSchema() *Schema {
    return &Schema{
        Schema: "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        ...
    }
}
```